# Rails Devise Omiauth callback return domain.com:443 instead of https://domain.com

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, devise

I'm using `AWS` for deploying my `Rails` app. The request flow likes this

```
request -> AWS ELB (80, 443 SSL) -> EC2 (80) force to use https -> Unicorn
```

I've just followed `devise` document and use the callback link `/users/auth/facebook`.

When run with `http` then it works fine, but when I force to load `https` on EC2 then the callback will return

`http://domain.com:443/users/auth/facebook`

instead of

`https://domain.com/users/auth/facebook`

Then it stucks here.

What should I check? Since I already recheck the `Nginx` config, setting on Facebook app...
Thanks!

### UPDATE

I tried to use this setting

```
80 ELB -> 80 EC2
443 ELB -> 443 EC2
```

And redirect http request to https on EC2 but the same issue happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two AWS Opsworks instances behind an Elastic Load Balancer.

The OpsWorks instances stack is Ruby on Rails + Nginx + Unicorn.

I want that my site is available both in http and https so for this reason I configured properly nginx server and in my Rails app **I left this row commented**:

**config/environments/production.rb**

```
# config.force_ssl = true
```

But I was having a problem like yours!

**PROBLEM:**

When a user login from http, everything is fine, but for users that are signing in from HTTPS, from facebook/twitter/instagram with devise omniauth, they were redirecting to a bad url like:
**http://www.examplesite.com:443**/users/auth/facebook/callback?code=xxx...xxx

I configured the ELB listener (inside AWS console) like you did in the way below, providing my certificate for the https part:
[image]

Note that HTTPS ==> **HTTP**

** The problem was inside my nginx configuration** and I fixed it deleting this line inside the 80 server parts:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
```

So at the end this is my nginx file (look unicorn inside servers 80):

```
upstream unicorn_examplesite.com {
  server unix:/srv/www/examplesite_pics/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 443 default deferred;
  server_name www.examplesite.com;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/examplesite.com.access.log;
  root /srv/www/examplesite_pics/current/public;

  location ~ ^/(system|assets|img|fonts|css|doc)/ {
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*";
    expires max;
    access_log off;
    allow all;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    break;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/examplesite.com.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/examplesite.com.key;
  ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers         ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256;
  ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_session_timeout 10m;

  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_read_timeout 60;
    proxy_send_timeout 60;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn_examplesite.com;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 70;
}

server {
  listen 80 default deferred;
  server_name www.examplesite.com;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/examplesite.com.access.log;
  root /srv/www/examplesite_pics/current/public;

  location ~ ^/(system|assets|img|fonts|css|doc)/ {
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*";
    expires max;
    access_log off;
    allow all;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    break;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;

  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_read_timeout 60;
    proxy_send_timeout 60;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn_examplesite.com;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 70;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name *.examplesite.com;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/examplesite.com.access.log;
  root /srv/www/examplesite_pics/current/public;

  location ~ ^/(system|assets|img|fonts|css|doc)/ {
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*";
    expires max;
    access_log off;
    allow all;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    break;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;

  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_read_timeout 60;
    proxy_send_timeout 60;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn_examplesite.com;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 70;
}

server {
  listen 443;
  server_name *.examplesite.com;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/examplesite.com.access.log;
  root /srv/www/examplesite_pics/current/public;

  location ~ ^/(system|assets|img|fonts|css|doc)/ {
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*";
    expires max;
    access_log off;
    allow all;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    break;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/examplesite.com.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/examplesite.com.key;
  ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers         ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256;
  ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_session_timeout 10m;

  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_read_timeout 60;
    proxy_send_timeout 60;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn_examplesite.com;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 70;
}

server {
  listen 443;
  server_name examplesite.com www.examplesite.it examplesite.it;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/examplesite.com.access.log;
  return 301 $scheme://www.examplesite.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name examplesite.com www.examplesite.it examplesite.it;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/examplesite.com.access.log;
  return 301 https://www.examplesite.com$request_uri;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you @Diego. I use the `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;` from a long time and I did not notice :D